# Console system() output into a int variable

Tags: c++, xcode, console, int, system

I'm trying to read the resolution of my screen by using the following system() function.

```
system("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution | uniq | awk '{print $2}' |  cut -d 'x' -f2");
```

Unfortunatly I can not use popen I'm working on Xcode and the program collapses with popen, so it has to be system(). But, the problem is that I don't know how to collect the data this system call is sending to the console into a int variable. I tried;

```
w << std::cerr << std::endl;
const std::string W(w.str());
int j = atoi(W.c_str());
cerr << "VALUE 2: " << j;
```

That's supposted to convert the cerr exit that system is giving into a a string, then a char and then finally a int :) but doesn't work.
Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"I can not use popen I'm working on Xcode and the program collapses with popen"* - there is no reason why you should not use popen with Xcode - perhaps the problem lies elsewhere ?

Comment: This is the code I'm running using popen, and seems to work, but then I archive the code into an app, I tried to lunch it and doesn't open. I remove the popen code an it opens. Here the code: FILE *output1;
    if(!(output1 = popen("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution | uniq | awk '{print $2}' |  cut -d 'x' -f2","r"))){}
    unsigned int i;
    fscanf(output1," %d",&i); m_width = i;
    pclose(output1);

Comment: `FILE *output2;
    if(!(output2 = popen("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution | uniq | awk '{print $4}' |  cut -d 'x' -f2","r"))){}
    unsigned int j;
    fscanf(output2," %d",&j); m_height = j;
    pclose(output2);`

Comment: SOLVED - Thanks for the answer Paul R, you were right popen worked!

Comment: Great - if you have time please post your solution as an answer in case someone else has similar problems in the future.